# Newtonsoft.json not working with Dotfuscator Xamarin PCL + Android release mode

Tags: xamarin.android, dotfuscator, preemptive

I am using Dotfuscator "PreEmptive Solutions" for my Xamarin.Android project.
The Newtonsoft.json library does not work in my PCL (it works fine in Xamarin.Android only) while I am using Dotfuscator for release mode.
If I disabled Dotfuscator the app works fine.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What kind of errors are you seeing? You may be experiencing errors because the obfuscation renames code elements that your JSON serialization depends on. If so, you may need to exclude some code elements from renaming. For a case study of discovering errors and configuring renaming exclusions, see [the Configure Renaming Exclusions](https://www.preemptive.com/obfuscating-xamarin-with-dotfuscator#pctoc-configure-renaming-exclusions) section of the Dotfuscator-Xamarin documentation. (*Disclaimer: I work for PreEmptive.*)

Answer (score 0):

if you link all assemblies from Android build --> linker

> **Note** make sure you choose **Release** mode from Configuration

you need yo ignore link this assemblies

```
SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_green;SQLite-net;
```

for more details

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/

[image]